# How to create a jQuery scroll to edit CSS?

Tags: jquery, css

In a lot of CSS examples there is this scrollbar to edit the CSS

[alt text http://img213.imageshack.us/img213/9206/scrollbar.png](http://img213.imageshack.us/img213/9206/scrollbar.png)

I can't find one article to do this,can someone explain how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, to make a slider change CSS:

```
$( "#slider" ).bind( "slidechange", function(event, ui) {
if (ui.value === 10) {
   $("#idTochange").css('background-color','red') 
//you can add any jQuery code you want to run here when the slider value = 10
} else if (ui.value === 15 {
    $("#idTochange").css('background-color','green')
} else {
   $("#idTochange").css('background-color','blue')
}
console.log(ui.value); //debug output of slider value, use this to change the if values above
});
```

Check http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/ for detailed info on how to instantiate a slider, and how to access the information returned by jQueryUI

Comment: Yes to modify CSS with the slider. Sorry I didn't explain much.

Comment: Okay so where it says 'background-color' and 'blue' and etc is where I can replace and put in something like 'width' '13px'?

Comment: Yes. That is where you can add jquery modifiers to the chain. See http://api.jquery.org/css

Comment: Right. Depending on the value specified in the if else statements (they are checking the value of the slide thru ui.value

Answer (score 3):

You can find some good examples of using the jQueryUI slider here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/